# R subset data by id value pattern

Tags: r, dataset

I am trying to make a subset of my data table (counties) consisting of rows where the id number ends in zero.  I have tried using grep and %like% but these are specific to the entire id value and not just the last integer value.

[image: The highlighted values are examples of what I would want to extract]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you. This includes not posting data as an image, and including (even if it didn't work) the code you tried.

Comment: Try something like `dat[grep('0$',dat$id),]`

Comment: Or if it's an integer: `ID %% 10 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from dat where Id like '%0'")
```

**OR** the `data.table` package: **As suggested by Frank**

```
dat[id %like% "0$"]
```